# Minimum time to reach B from A: Iran Math Olympiad 2001

Tags: geometry, optimization, contest-math

In this picture: a runner wants reach B by starting at A. Velocity in White space is  $10 m/s$ and in brown space is $5 m/s$. what is the minimum time that he need? 
I upload original image of question but it wrote in Farsi. Assume that Brown region is a an unbounded band along the $y$ axis.

[image]
[image: origianl image]

$$a)\sqrt{26}$$
$$b)\sqrt{20}$$
$$c)5$$
$$d)\sqrt{30}$$
$$e)\sqrt{34}$$

Comment: Intuitively: It is the best to start from $A$ and move diagonally to $B$ until you reach the brown space. Then there are two options that you need to consider: The first is to keep moving diagonally until you reach $B$, the second is to move horizontally so you escape the brown space and then move diagonally towards $B$. There are only those two options to check

Comment: Thats right. But what's the minimum time?

Comment: What difficulty have you in computing the times for the two routes?

Comment: @saulspatz I try to find a definite answer. But I can't/ You could try it. I think answer is the non of the mentioned in main question and is bigger than $6 seconds$ time.

Comment: Why do you think it is bigger than $6$ seconds?  What answers do you get for the two routes mentioned by @Yanko?  Please show your work.

Comment: OK. I'll write my answer bellow.

Comment: @saulspatz please look  at my answer!

Comment: Please see my correct answer.

Comment: You are correct: none of the suggested answers can possibly be right. How embarrassing! I assume that the clueless examiners thought along the lines of user376343's deleted answer, with $\sqrt 34$ as the solution. Another problem is that it might be faster to go around the top, avoiding the brown region altogether. But the figure is unclear $-$ we would need a scan of the original to know. In any case, going around the top, although it will take less than $6$ seconds, can hardly equal any of the suggested solutions either.

Comment: I could upload that image. But original question wrote in Farsi. Assume that Brown region is a an unbounded band along the $y$ axis.

Comment: @TonyK I add original image.

Comment: Use the path of light concept using Fermat's principle and the problem is a toast

Comment: @AdityaGarg: If you are trying to say that the problem is easy, I must disagree with you. Conceptually perhaps, but computing the answer is certainly not, as Parcly Taxel's answer shows.

Comment: Dear all. How could I mark more than one of the answers as correct?

Answer (score 7):

*None of the provided answers are correct.* The minimum time is an algebraic number of degree 8, as I will show.

Model the problem such that the runner starts at the origin, $B=(40,30)$ and the slow strip is $20<x<30$. Now let the runner meet the slow strip at $(20,a)$ and exit it at $(30,b)$, with straight lines in between. The time taken is then
$$s=\newcommand{hypot}{\operatorname{hypot}}\frac{\hypot(20,a)}{10}+\frac{\hypot(10,b-a)}5+\frac{\hypot(10,30-b)}{10}$$
I turned this into a polynomial expression in $a,b,s$, then using techniques very similar to those used in [another answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2651575), derived minimal polynomials for the three variables:
$$s^8-68s^6+5266s^4-177036s^2+845325=0;s=6.121773\dots$$
$$27a^4-1080a^3+24800a^2-576000a+5760000=0;a=17.661784\dots$$
$$27b^4-2700b^3+103400b^2-1758000b+11070000=0;b=21.169107\dots$$

Comment: Can we solve as if there is one white area $20+10$ wide, so that $s=hypot(30,a)/10+hypot(10,30-a)/5$? Does that produce the same answer with simpler equations?

Comment: How do we know that this octic equation is not reducible?  [Snell's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law) says it should be.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Because I checked with Singular.

Comment: @nickgard You get the same result for $s$ if you push the slow strip towards $B$, so that $B$ lies on its edge. The minimal polynomial for $s$ remains the same, while that for the $y$-coordinate of the entry point $a$ roots the quartic $3a^4-180a^3+6200a^2-216000a+3240000$ and is around $26.492677$.

Comment: Are you replaced entry and exit point? because you used $(20,a)$ as meet brown band and $(30,b)$ as exit band.

Comment: What is hypot? Please add more details to your answer.

Comment: @BarzanHayati $\operatorname{hypot}(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. And I can't understand your first comment.

Comment: Your argument: "Now let the runner meet the slow strip at $(20,a)$ and exit it at $(30,b)$, with straight lines in between" . while you started at $B$ meet brown band at $(30,b)$ and exit at $(20,a)$.

Comment: @BarzanHayati There's no issue there. It is easy to see that the runner must take a straight line within each section to minimise time; thus only the boundaries need paying attention to.

Comment: OK! but for a student and approximately 5 minutes time for this question, how could reach your answer? However it might be more correct than my answer.

Comment: @BarzanHayati You can't reach this in five minutes without a computer because the polynomial manipulations required are very involved. As it is, the question should not even have been posed in the first place.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel So if we use the Snell's Law the answer is wrong?

Comment: @S.H.W No, the question is wrong. Period.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Why question is wrong?

Comment: @S.H.W Because I've shown (as well as others) that it has no correct answers as written.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Okay. Snell's Law and your answer produce the same answer, right?

Answer (score 5):

I assume that runner moves like this picture:

[image: Path]

Calculating time of moving:

$$t=\frac{d_{1}}{10} + \frac{d_{2}}{5}+\frac{d_{3}}{10}=\frac{d_{1}+d_{2}+d_{3}}{10}+\frac{d_{2}}{10}  $$

we know that $d_{1}\ge20$, $d_{2}\ge10$ and $d_{3}\ge10$
Also : Direct path between $A$ and $B$ has the minimum length: So 
$d_{1}+d_{2}+d_{3}\ge AB$. And $AB=50$

$$ t \ge \frac{AB}{10}+1\ge 6$$

So minimum time is at least $6$.

If I move horizontally in brown region, absolutely it take more than $6$ seconds.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, so far as I can see.  It should have been part of the question though, in my opinion.

Comment: This looks correct. I either fell into the trap claiming $\sqrt{34}$ and the test authors also, or there is a hidden mistaken judgement.

Comment: @user376343 I add some argument to your answer. Please look at it.

Comment: I checked my answer and I am going to delete it.  Even if it is the largest from the values  proposed in the problem, it is too small.    Your arguments are right, but do not prove that 6 is minimum (that it is achieved). Wolframalpha gives a minimum about $6.12177$

Answer (score 5):

That would be the same path that a light ray would take, through media with different refractive indices.

[image: Run_in_sand_1]

Without loss of generality, we can move the "sand" stripe to start at B.
Then the optical analogy will tell us that the refractive index of "sand" is
$2$ and that 
$$
\sin \theta _{\,2}  = 2\sin \theta _{\,1} 
$$

Without going into precise calculations, we can consider that
$$
3/4 < \tan \theta _{\,2}  < 1
$$
so that $\theta _{\,1} $ will be approximately $\pi / 8$ , which means $ \tan \theta _{\,1}  \approx \sqrt{2}-1 \approx 0.4$.

Therefore the path will enter the sand strip about $4$ m below $B$.

The time is then approximately
$$
t \approx {{\sqrt {100 + 16} } \over 5} + {{\sqrt {900 + 26^{\,2} } } \over {10}} \approx {{11} \over 5} + {{40} \over {10}} \approx 6.2 \approx \sqrt {38} 
$$
and yes, $\sqrt {34}$ looks to be too low.

Note that the path that goes straight up at $45^\circ$and then horizontally across the "sand" would take
$$
t = {{10} \over 5} + {{\sqrt {1800} } \over {10}} = 2 + 3\sqrt 2  = 6.24
$$
while the straight line from $A$ to $B$ would take
$$
t = {{\sqrt {100 + 900/16} } \over 5} + {{30\sqrt {1 + 9/16} } \over {10}} = {{50} \over {20}} + {{150} \over {40}} = {{250} \over {40}} = 6.25
$$

*--  notes --*

The optical analogy helps in saying that, the piecewise path from A to B which attains the minimum time to be traversed
shall obey to the [Refraction Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction)
$$
{{\sin \theta _{\,1} } \over {\sin \theta _{\,2} }} = {{v_{\,1} } \over {v_{\,2} }} = {{n_{\,2} } \over {n_{\,1} }}
$$
which is valid also for mechanical particles (and for humans).

[image: Run_in_sand_2]

Since the above law is bidirectional, then we will have the situation depicted in this sketch, to confirm that the horizontal placement of the 
sand strip is *ininfluential* on the total time.

The exact solution will translate into finding the solution to
$$
\eqalign{
  & 10\tan \theta _{\,1}  + 30\tan \theta _{\,2}  = 30\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad 10{{\sin \theta _{\,1} } \over {\sqrt {1 - \sin ^{\,2} \theta _{\,1} } }} + 30{{2\sin \theta _{\,1} } \over {\sqrt {1 - 4\sin ^{\,2} \theta _{\,1} } }} - 30 = 0 \cr} 
$$
which leads to a 4-th degree equation, as already evidenced in a previous answer.

Comment: Downvoted because I think this is too broad for this problem and does not effectively tackle the question. However, I do agree about the physics interpretation.

Comment: Yes. How much could be that?

Comment: well, actually it was a hint: I completed now the answer to show how the optical analogy can help to solve the problem.

Comment: I think this answer is very helpful. I can't believe six users recommended deleting it.

Comment: @TonyK: well actually, what was deleted was my original answer, which consisted of only the first line.. was intended as an obvious (and I was thinking, useful) hint .. but it was not .. caught. Wish the extension of it will receive better attention, and thanks for yours.

Comment: Ah, OK, that makes sense.

Comment: @GCab I think for prove this problem using light, you should consider this in mind that min time depends on 3 section not 2 first section. They are not independent of each other!

Comment: @BarzanHayati: I added a further note, which justifies that the sand strip can be placed wherever in the mid of the path, without affecting the total (minimal) time.

Comment: @GCab Thanks for your solution. Now I'm too busy. I look at your solution as early as possible and after that I mark correct solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Traversing the sand stripe takes the same amount of time as traversing twice as much white area, so if we replace the sand with a white stripe of twice the width, it will take the same amount of time to cross. $t = \sqrt{30^2+50^2}/10=\sqrt{34}$, or answer (e).

Comment: Please be patient. @Bill is a new contributor and don't give him negative score.

Comment: Don’t understand why someone downvoted Bill. His answer is the correct, and obvious one. Why would anyone think his answer is incorrect? The only issue is sqrt(34) is answer (e), not (d). Is that the reason?

Comment: @uday The problem with the answer is that the _question_ is cooked, as I have shown; there are no correct answers out of the ones given.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel , i don’t know the concept of minimum polynomials. Does it give the same answer if you differentiate the expression for s in your answer with respect to a and b ?

Comment: @uday Yes.${}{}$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel , I ran a loop and got slightly different answers. s = 6.177999, which is very close to sqrt(38) which gcab wrote in his answer, a=13.210321, b=16.789679. And, yes, agree that sqrt(34) won’t work. Although, I suspect the person who framed the question expected someone use the argument that Bill wrote.

Comment: @uday You got the wrong answer. $6.12$ is shorter.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yeah, you are right. I get the same answers. Had a mistake earlier.